# Start counting up when countdown hits 0 | Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a countdown script that I found online, but when it hit's zero the count continues negative. Could someone help me fix it in a way that when it reaches zero, it will start counting back up again? The count up from zero should be infinite. No jQuery please. Thank you!

```
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Jul 10, 2020 15:00:00').getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

        document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

    }, second)
```

Comment: You want to start back again from which date in future?

Comment: Hi, on July 10 2020 at 15:00 the countdown will hit zero. From that moment I would like that it starts counting up again.

Comment: up to which date?

Comment: `distance = Math.abs(countDown - now)`

Comment: The count up should be infinite, no end date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Math.abs`, you can always end up with a positive integer:

```js
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Jul 10, 2020 15:00:00').getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = Math.abs(countDown - now);

        document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

    }, second)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Richie, that did it!